# File Upload Size Issue In Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a input field I'have upload a document in .pdf format. I'm checking the file size through below code for IE and others browser, but it fails in new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") for IE. When I go to Internet Options->Security->Custom Level->Enable Initialize and script ActiveX Controls than it working fine but when I disable it, it didn't work. By default ActiveX Controls is disabled in IE, so not a best practice go to and enable it. Is there any other way to check file size .

Help me, thanks in advance.

```
        function GetFileSize(fileid) {
            debugger;
            try {
                var fileSize = 0;

                //for IE
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    //before making an object of ActiveXObject,
                    //please make sure ActiveX is enabled in your IE browser
                    var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); var filePath = $("#" + fileid)[0].value;
                    var objFile = objFSO.getFile(filePath);
                    var fileSize = objFile.size; //size in kb
                    fileSize = fileSize / 1048576; //size in mb
                }
                    //for FF, Safari, Opeara and Others
                else {
                    fileSize = $("#" + fileid)[0].files[0].size //size in kb
                    fileSize = fileSize / 1048576; //size in mb
                }
                return fileSize;
            }
            catch (e) {
                //alert("Error is :" + e);
            }
        }
```

Working fine for other browsers but not in IE.

Comment: `FileSizeInMB = FileSizeInKB / 1024;`

Comment: You are declaring twice `fileSize` by the way.

Comment: What is the version of jQuery you're using?

Comment: Is there any way to get file size from jQuery in IE.I'm using 1.6.4 version of jQuery